# How can I add shadow to an icon in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to add shadows to some icons in my flutter project. I've checked the icon class constructors but nothing points to that. Any idea on how to implement that?

Comment: Probably related to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18384

Comment: No, the issue discussed here relates to alternative icon themes

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I got what i wanted eventually using this workaround. I hope it helps whoever might need something similar.

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
      left: 1.0,
      top: 2.0,
      child: Icon(icon, color: Colors.black54),
    ),
    Icon(icon, color: Colors.white),
  ],
),
```

Comment: ewwww... that feels dirty.

Comment: Not pretty, but it does the trick! Adding some alpha make it even better.

Comment: this does look dirty, but look down. its the cleanest solution out of all

Answer (score 31):

The Icon widget has a shadows property with which you can give shadows to an icon.

```html
const Icon(
     icon,
     shadows: <Shadow>[Shadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 15.0)],
     size: 60,
     color: Colors.white,
)
```

Comment: Out of all the suggestions, I found this to be the easiest and best looking solution

Comment: For better results, throw in some offset with a `black45`, e.g. `<Shadow>[Shadow(color: Colors.black45, blurRadius: 20.0, offset: Offset(0, 2.0))]`

Answer (score 11):

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,               
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey[400]!,
        blurRadius: 5.0,
      ),
    ]
  ),
  child: Icon(
    Icons.fiber_manual_record,
    color: Colors.amber,
    size:15,
  )
),
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: How can I add shadow to other icon, it was working fine with fiber_manual_record.

Comment: update your code to null safety adding `!` in color.

Answer (score 6):

*You can use* **`IconShadowWidget()`**. 
[image]

***How to use:***

**1. add dependencies to** `pubspec.yaml`**:**

```
 icon_shadow: ^1.0.1
```

**2. Import your Dart code :**

```
import 'package:icon_shadow/icon_shadow.dart';
```

**3. add icons:**

```
Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
        IconShadowWidget(
          Icon(
            Icons.add_circle,
            color: Colors.red,
            size: 100.0,
          ),
        ),
        IconShadowWidget(
          Icon(
            Icons.add_circle,
            color: Colors.red,
            size: 100.0,
          ),
          shadowColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        IconShadowWidget(
          Icon(
            Icons.add_circle,
            color: Colors.red,
            size: 100.0,
          ),
          shadowColor: Colors.black,
          showShadow: false,
        ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

You can also check my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/AbirAhsan/flutter_Icon-Image_shadow)

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you need elevation/shadow, remember the `Card` widget. So, you can wrap it with `Card` and `SizedBox`:

[image]

```
          Card(
          elevation: 10,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
          ),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 35,
            height: 35,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.close,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 19,
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Even better, here is an icon button with material bubble effect + shadow (in below GIF, shadow's quality looks like bad, it is because of GIF itself)

[image: Material icon button with shadow]:

```
          Card(
          elevation: 10,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
          ),
          child: ClipOval(
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.transparent, // button color
              child: InkWell(
                splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 35,
                  height: 35,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 19,
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

Took the idea from @Dzeri answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55668093/414635) and encapsulated it into a Widget so it became reusable.

### Widget

```dart
class ShadowIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final Color color;

  ShadowIcon(this.icon, {Key key, this.color: kLight}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          left: 0.5,
          top: 0.5,
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(
              sigmaX: 1.0,
              sigmaY: 1.0,
            ),
            child: FaIcon(this.icon, color: kDark.withOpacity(0.7)),
          ),
        ),
        FaIcon(this.icon, color: color),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The `BackdropFilter` doesn't seem to be working as expected but anyway all I needed was a subtle drop shadow. I'm also using the package [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter) but you can replace the `FaIcon` by the native `Icon` widget.

### Usage

Your can simply replace the native `Icon` by the `ShadowIcon` widget call:

```dart
IconButton(
  icon: ShadowIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.chevronLeft, color: kLight),
  onPressed: () => Get.back(),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

Right now, it's not possible to directly add shadows to an Icon widget. You can however use the additional information from your IconData icon to display the icon as a styled text.

```
Text(
  String.fromCharCode(Icons.add.codePoint), 
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: Icons.add.fontFamily,
    color: Colors.white, 
    fontSize: 20.0,
    shadows: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: ColorTheme.blackLight,
        spreadRadius: 2,
        blurRadius: 2,
      )
    ],
    height: 1 //if this isn't set, the shadow will be cut off on the top and bottom
  )
);
```

Comment: This is the smartest way to do it since it allows using Shadow (not BoxShadow, I need Shadow), but unfortunately, it doesn't work inside an IconButton, at least on the web. It shows an invalid character instead of the real character.

Comment: @HamzaAbbad I use this with IconButton on flutter web and it works now.
My problem is the spreadRadius not worked for shadow, but other things work well.

Answer (score 2):

```
  InkWell(
      child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                             color: Colors.white,
                             shape: BoxShape.circle,
                             boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  blurRadius: .5,
                                ),
                              ]),
                child: Icon(
                         Icons.clear,
                         color: Colors.black,
                         size: 25,
                          )),
                    ),
```

result will be like this pic:

[image: circle icon button with shadow]:

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use the icon font.

```
GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, top: 10),
                    child: Text('\u{e5d3}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons',
                            shadows: [
                              BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 2)
                            ])),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {}
)

Icon data from icons.dart
/// <i class="material-icons md-36">more_horiz</i> &#x2014; material icon named "more horiz".
static const IconData more_horiz = IconData(0xe5d3, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [decorated icon](https://pub.dev/packages/decorated_icon) plugin to do shadow on icon

[image]

Code here :

```
Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        DecoratedIcon(
          Icons.android,
          color: Colors.purple,
          size: 60.0,
          shadows: [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 42.0,
              color: Colors.purpleAccent,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 12.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        DecoratedIcon(
          Icons.favorite,
          color: Colors.lightBlue.shade50,
          size: 60.0,
          shadows: [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 12.0,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 12.0,
              color: Colors.green,
              offset: Offset(0, 6.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        DecoratedIcon(
          Icons.fingerprint,
          color: Colors.orange,
          size: 60.0,
          shadows: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black,
              offset: Offset(3.0, 3.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: That is perfect. Works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty late, but for anyone looking to add a shadow in circular form should wrap the icon with a CircleAvatar widget and set the backgroundColor proprety of CircleAvatar to Colors.grey.withOpacity (0.5) or to any other color for the shadow. Here's the code snippet

```
CircleAvatar (
bacgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity (0.5),
child: Icon (
Icons.yourIcon
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Container(
  width: 30,
  height: 30,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
    boxShadow: const [
      BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, blurRadius: 1),
    ],
  ),
  child: const Icon(
    FontAwesomeIcons.checkCircle,
    size: 30,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
),
```

If the container size is the same as the icon size, then 3 pixels will be always downward, This is because I don't know. but this solution will clear it.

Make sure that the container size will increase by 3 pixels with icons size.

```dart
Container(
  width: 33,
  height: 33,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
      boxShadow: const [
        BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, blurRadius: 1),
      ]),
  child: const Icon(
    FontAwesomeIcons.checkCircle,
    size: 30,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Material(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  elevation: 10,
  child: Icon(
    icons.add,

  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

base on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55668093/10610847) you can use this code and maybe add some change

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IconShadowView extends Icon {
  const IconShadowView(super.icon,
      {super.key,
      super.color,
      super.semanticLabel,
      super.shadows,
      super.size,
      super.textDirection});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          left: 1.0,
          top: 2.0,
          child: Icon(
            icon,
            color: Colors.black,
            key: key,
            semanticLabel: semanticLabel,
            shadows: shadows,
            size: size,
            textDirection: textDirection,
          ),
        ),
        super.build(context),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```